# Почему dict в python требует ([()])

Tags: python, dict

Изучаю питон. Конспектирую словари, не понимаю почему синтаксис `dict()` такой странный. Как работать с `list()` или `tuple()` предельно понятно, но у `dict` какие то свои правила. Как создать словарь с помощью литерала - ясно. Как с помощью `dict()` тоже, по крайней мере в случае с объявлением переменных в самом `dict()`. Но непонятно, почему нельзя передать ему те же две переменные, но уже объявленные вне `dict()`? Зачем городить какие то `[()]` внутри этого `dict()` при попытке передать ему объекты напрямую?

Почему это `dict_test=dict([(1,'Один'), (2,'Два')])` - работает,

а это  `dict_test=dict((1,'Один'), (2,'Два'))` - нет, python ругается на то, что агрументов было передано 2, в то время как `dict()` якобы может принять только один? Почему он принимает только список кортежей? Ведь по идее с неизменяемым типом он должен как раз хорошо взаимодействовать?

Comment: Потому что dict может принять только один аргумент — коллекцию пар ключ-значение. И такой коллекцией может быть например список `[]`, но никто не запрещает использовать любую другую коллекцию

Comment: Пример очень странной коллекции https://repl.it/repls/TotalPointlessUnderstanding#main.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы хотите передать в конструктор генератор пар. Метод `dict` может принимать `iterable`-структуру, в том числе и генератор. Но для него нужен `generator comprehension` типа:

```
dict((i, i + 1) for i in range(10))
```

или

```
dict((("a", 1), ("b", 2)))
```

потому что `tuple` тоже являются `iterable`-объектами, как и генераторы.

По методу `dict` есть неплохая [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) сказано, что тот может принимать

Comment: Во втором примере у вас `tuple`, а не `generator` )

Comment: `gen = ((i, i+1) for i in range(10))`

Comment: Вот тут: `dict((("a", 1), ("b", 2)))` нет генератора, про которые у вас там кругом написано )

Comment: Да, всё верно) Хотя `tuple` тоже является инстансом `iterable`

Answer (score 2):

```
dict([(1,'Один'), (2,'Два')])
```

передаёте одни объект - `[(1,'Один'), (2,'Два')]`

---

```
dict((1,'Один'), (2,'Два'))
```

передаёте два объекта - `(1,'Один')` и `(2,'Два')`

---

Если их взять в круглые скобки, т.е. в `tuple`

```
dict(((1,'Один'), (2,'Два')))
```

передаёте одни объект - `((1,'Один'), (2,'Два'))` и все работает

Comment: Вы там забыли ещё одни скобки во втором примере с `dict((1,'Один'), (2,'Два'))`

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, не заметил

Answer (score 2):

Ну вообще-то `list` в такой форме тоже не работает:

```
list(1, 2)

TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Потому что и `dict` и `list` хотят на вход `iterable`, из элементов которого они и заполняются.

В качестве `iterable` можно передать и список, и кортеж, и генератор, внутри которого уже для списка могут быть одиночные элементы, а вот для словаря нужно два элемента, поэтому внутри должен быть кортеж, например, поэтому и возникают ещё одни скобки - один дополнительный уровень вложенности по сравнению с инициализацией списка.